# How do i update variable globally in Angular typescript or jquery.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, variables

When I update `this.showPlan = true;` i guess it is not updatiing globally because when clicking on document it is still showing as `false` instead of `true`

This is my HTML code:

```
<li (click)="displayPlanWidget()"></li>
<div style="display: none;" id="planTabInput">----</div>
```

This is my type script code:

```
public showPlan:boolean = false;     //For showPlan

ngOnInit() {
    var arg1 = this.showPlan;
    var arg2 = this.showAccount;

    console.log('arg1--------'+arg1); //coming fine on initial
    jQuery(document).click({showPlan:arg1},function(e) {
        console.log('showPlan--------'+e.data.showPlan); //coming as false insted true

        if(e.data.showPlan != 'false') { //this should trigger (not triggering because it is not updating to true)
            jQuery("#planTabInput").css( "display",'none' );
        }
    });
}


public displayPlanWidget() {
    this.showPlan = true;

  console.log('showPlan Changed to '+this.showPlan); //coming true(fine) 

  jQuery("#planTabInput").show();
}
```

Where I am doing wrong help is appreciated.

Comment: You can achieve it using Services

Comment: @Swanand can u give a link or ref to that.!

Comment: Here is the link http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.in/2017/08/angular-singleton-service.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really all you need for the functionality you need to implement. Angular recommends avoiding direct [DOM manipulation](https://angular.io/guide/security#avoid-direct-use-of-the-dom-apis)

`<li (click)="displayPlanWidget()"></li>
     <div [hidden]="!showPlan" id="planTabInput">----</div>`

```
import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

public showPlan = false;     //For showPlan
public showAccount = true; //For showAccount
@Output('activeWidget') activeWidget = new EventEmitter<string>();

public toggleWidget() {
    this.showPlan = !this.showPlan;
    this.showAccount = !this.showAccount;
    this.activeWidget.next((this.showAccount ? 'showAccount' : 'showPlan'))
}
```

Comment: how it's known to other components.?

Comment: @mehany apart from toggle I want `Popup should be closed` when I click outside of the both popup's

Comment: If you need some UI components, you probably better off using existing community modules and read the docs. Consider this project for example https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin, you can learn a lot from it and reuse its components